# Class not being added in VUE

Tags: css, laravel, vuejs2

I have a input filed and when it is typed in i have a method which checks the length of the inputted string, this works fine, however i now want to add a class depending on the length of the string.

This is my template element:

```
<input v-model=“categoryTitle” v-bind:class="{ ‘passed’: isPassed }" @keyup=“addName” type=“text” name=“desc” id=“desc” value="" data-original="" placeholder="">
```

and this is my data and method:

```
data:{
categoryTitle:’’,
isPassed:false,
},
methods: {

        addName(){

            if(this.categoryTitle.length < 100 && this.categoryTitle.length > 0){
                this.isPassed = true;
            }

        },

    }
```

But nothing is happening, what am i doing wrong? i am still quite new to VUE so im sure it is a rookie error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `isPassed` a computed property:

```
computed: {
  isPassed() {
    let length = this.categoryTitle.length;
    return length < 100 && length > 0;
  }
}
```

That way you don't need to update the property by listening to an event on the input. The computed property will update automatically when the value of the dependant `categoryTitle` property changes.

Here's a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { categoryTitle: '' }
  },
  computed: {
    isPassed() {
      let length = this.categoryTitle.length;
      return length < 100 && length > 0;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.passed { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="categoryTitle" v-bind:class="{ passed: isPassed }">
</div>
```